# How to mock a slice pipe in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

*I am trying to write test cases for a component that uses a slice pipe. I checked several links telling how to mock a pipe for component unit testing. Here issue is that it is an inbuilt pipe so I don't know how tranform method will be.*

```
         <tr *ngFor="let item of filteredUsers  |slice: (page-1) * pageSize : page * pageSize | searchFilter:searchText
            ">
                <td><input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(item.id, $event.target.checked)"></td>
                <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.surname}}</td>
                <td>{{item.phoneNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                <td>{{item.grossIncome}}</td>
                <!-- <td>{{item.createdDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }} </td> -->

            </tr>
```

**Code for spec**

```
  describe('fetchUserList()',()=>{
    it('should get list of users from notification service',()=>{
  // component.pageSize=10;
 
  component.pageOptions=[10,20,50,100];
  notificationServiceSpy.fetchUserList.and.returnValue(of({}))
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.userList.length).toBe(0);
  expect(component.userList).toEqual(component.filteredUsers);
  expect(component.userCountLogs.length).toBe(0);
  expect(notificationServiceSpy.fetchUserList).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

**Here is the code for ngOnit hook**

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.pageOptions=[10,20,50,100];
this.pageSize=this.pageOptions[0];
this.userMappingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  topicId: ['', Validators.required],
  users: this.formBuilder.array([])
});

 this.fetchNotificationTopic();
 this.fetchUserList();
}
```

**Here is the code for fetching user's list**

```
fetchUserList() {
this.topicList = [];
this.notificationService.fetchUserList(null).subscribe((data: any) => {
  if (data) {
     this.userList =this.filteredUsers= data;

    this.userCountLogs = data.length;
  }

}, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

});

}
```

[image]

Comment: SlicePipe should accept an array to work with, so my guess is that the error occurs because you configure fetchUserList to return (an observable of) an object (empty in your case, but still an object).

Comment: Thanks your suggestion resolved my issue. Can you tell how can I handle the HttpErrorResponse in unit test?

Comment: Check for the rxjs operator throwError.